# Reason for thickness of pepper\eggplant paste

Tags: eggplant, pepper

When making pepper or eggplant paste (roasted then blended), the paste is very thick, even gel-like. Why is that? What ingredient in the fruit's cells thickens it so? Or is it a very low water-content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a combination of the fruits fiber makeup as well as how much pectin is the fruit. High pectin fruits will jelly easily which is helping to thicken your paste along with the fibrous part of the fruits.